# How to obtain the correct titles when compiling several beamers together with docmute?

Tags: beamer, titles

I have two `beamer presentations` with their own fancy title. I eventually may need to deliver these two presentations together, so I'm trying to create a new document where I compile all these `beamers` together in a single document.

The presentation of paper 1 is represented by `MWE 1.tex` below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Paper 1 Fancy Title}
\author{Some Fancy Author}
\institute{Some Fancy Institute}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

{\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}{\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\frame{\titlepage}}}

\begin{frame}
Some fancy text 1
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The presentation of paper 2 is represented by `MWE 2.tex` below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Paper 2 Fancy Title}
\author{Some Fancy Author}
\institute{Some Fancy Institute}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

{\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}{\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\frame{\titlepage}}}

\begin{frame}
Some fancy text 2
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The general `beamer` where I try to compile both presentations together, which we'll call `MWE 3.tex`, is below:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage{docmute} % To compile several beamers into one

\title{Some Fancy Title}
\author{Some Fancy Author}
\institute{Some Fancy Institute}
\date{\today}

% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\part{mwe1}
\input{MWE 1}
\part{mwe2} 
\input{MWE 2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see in the output above, the problem I encounter with my approach is that the general "Some Fancy Title" appears in slides 1, 2 and 4. Instead, the general "Some Fancy Title" should only appear in slide 1, whereas Slide 2 should contain "Paper 1 Fancy Title" and slide 4 should contain "Paper 2 Fancy Title" (rather than the general "Some Fancy Title"). **How can I achieve that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the package `docmute` explicitly ignores everything given before the `\begin{documentclass}` in the inputed files. To obtain the disred output, it suffices to specify the contents of the title after `begin{document}` in both `MWE 1.tex` and `MWE 2.tex`. Hence, `MWE 3.tex` remains as it is:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage{docmute} % To compile several beamers into one

\title{Some Fancy Title}
\author{Some Fancy Author}
\institute{Some Fancy Institute}
\date{\today}

% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\part{mwe1}
\input{MWE 1}
\part{mwe2} 
\input{MWE 2}

\end{document}
```

Whereas `MWE 1.tex` as well as `MWE 2.tex` are modified as follows. For `MWE 1.tex`,

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Paper 1 Fancy Title}
\author{Some Fancy Author}
\institute{Some Fancy Institute}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

{\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}{\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\frame{\titlepage}}}

\begin{frame}
Some fancy text 1
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Analogously, for `MWE 2.tex`,

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Paper 2 Fancy Title}
\author{Some Fancy Author}
\institute{Some Fancy Institute}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

{\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}{\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\frame{\titlepage}}}

\begin{frame}
Some fancy text 2
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As it can be seen in the picture below, we obtain the desired output:

[image]